# Método para calcular promedio no me da el resultado correcto

Tags: javascript

Tengo que armar un código para calcular un promedio.

Nos dieron un ejemplo de como hacerlo y yo lo hice casi igual, con una diferencia de que a los números los elijo yo mediante `prompt`.

El problema es que al realizar el cálculo no me da el promedio, es como si no me ingresará bien los números al array, ya no tengo más ideas.

Gracias de antemano

```js
const calcularPromedio = numeros => { 
   let suma = 0; 
     for(let i = 0; i < numeros.length ; i++){
       suma += numeros[i]
     } 
    return suma / cantidad
 }

let cantidad = 5;
let numeros = [];

for(let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
  let lista = prompt("ingrese numero");
  console.log(lista)
  numeros.push(lista)
}

let resultado = calcularPromedio(numeros);
console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: Saludos, por favor pulsa [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/608413/edit) y agrega el código y mensaje de la consola en formato de texto, no como capturas de pantalla. ;)

Comment: Además de mostrar el código _como texto, con formato_, pon un título descriptivo, y corrige la etiqueta, porque estoy segura de que no colocaste el mouse encima de ella para ver su descripción: ___No debe confundirse con javascript___ :)

Comment: Buenas , apenas pueda lo arreglo, solo q hice la pregunta desde el celular y el código lo tengo en la computadora

Comment: no se ve como obtienes cantidad, asegúrate de agregarlo para tener un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te sucede es que tu prompt está leyendo string y no números. Cuando los sumás, estos se concatenan como palabras en lugar de sumarse como números.

La solución es convertir a número el elemento antes de sumarlo, en la función `calcularPromedio`.

```
 const calcularPromedio = num => { 
   let suma = 0; 
     for(let i = 0; i < num.length ; i++){
       suma += Number(num[i]) // Convierto este string en number
     } 
    return suma / cantidad
 }
```

Comment: Listo muchas gracias por todo, en el pdf que me dieron no decia algo de eso ,por eso tuve que recurrir a preguntar , gracias